# jquery show/hide submenu -> Hide one submenu if other was clicked

Tags: jquery

I need to close a submenu and open a new one if some other submenu was clicked, it means I do not want more than one submenu opened at a time. However all of the submenus should be able to close.

Here is my jquery script:

```
<script> 
  $('.show_hide').hide();
  $("li:has(ul)").click(function(){
  $("ul",this).toggle('slow');
  });
</script>
```

And html:

```
 <ul id="left-menu" class="menu-v">
   <li> 
     <a>Menu</a>
     <ul class="menu-v show_hide">
       <li>
         <a >submenu </a>
       </li>
       <li>
         <a >submenu 2</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why is there a `});` outside the `</script>` tag?

Comment: @siidheesh I just removed this whilst editing.

Comment: I dont understand. Please use jsFiddle for code. I will help You. http://jsfiddle.net/7qyE9/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe want like this ( I gave you example) -> http://jsfiddle.net/7qyE9/3/

html:

```
 <ul>
     <li class="main-menu">
         <span>Test</span>
         <ul class="submenu">
             <li>Item1</li>
             <li>Item2</li>
         </ul>
     </li>

     <li class="main-menu">
         <span>Abcde</span>
         <ul class="submenu">
             <li>Item3</li>
             <li>Item4</li>
         </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

and javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".main-menu .submenu").hide();

    $(".main-menu span").click(function(){
        $(".main-menu .submenu").hide('fast');
        $(this).parent().find("ul").toggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: Snake Eyes, thanks for this helpful yet a simple effective solution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what you're looking for, if you'd care to elaborate a little more I may be able to improve my answer.

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLwjH/) example

**HTML**

```
<ul id="left-menu" class="menu-v">
     <li>
        <ul class="show_hide">
           <li>
             <a >submenu </a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a >submenu 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
       <ul class="show_hide">
          <li>
             <a >submenu 4</a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a >submenu 5</a>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>​
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.show_hide').hide();
    $("li:has(ul)").click(function() {
        $("ul", this).toggle('slow');
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a>0 Level menu<a></li>
    <li><a>0 Level menu<a></li>
    <li><a>0 Level menu<a></li>
    <li class="parentMenu">
        <ul>
            <li class="alwaysShow"><a>0 Level menu<a><li>
            <li class="hidden"><a>1 Level menu<a><li>
            <li class="hidden"><a>1 Level menu<a><li>
            <li class="hidden"><a>1 Level menu<a><li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### JQUERY

```
$(".parentMenu").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).find(".hidden").show("100");
        },
        function () {
            $(this).find(".hidden").hide("100");
        }
);
```